# python : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've got a simple, straight forward question - please look at the code :

```
import openpyxl
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

preq   = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/Ians/Desktop/_complete.xlsx')
preqWb = preq.get_sheet_names()
preqAS = preq.get_sheet_by_name(preqWb[0])
newRwa = open('/Users/Ians/Desktop/newRwa.xlsx','w')
for i in range(2, 101):
    a=preqAS['A'+str(i)].value <==== correct value printed
    b=preqAS['B'+str(i)].value <==== correct value printed
    newRwa.write(a,b)   <=========== error line TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

newRwa.close()
```

Comment: newRwa is just an open file object and not a workbook.

Comment: exactly, I just wanted to put something from a spreadsheet to file, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Why should it work? Please follow the instructions in the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating and saving the output file using the `openpyxl` library's inbuilt methods.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

newRwa = Workbook()
ws1 = newRwa.active
for i in range(2,101):
    a = preqAS['A'+str(i)].value
    b = preqAS['B'+str(i)].value
    ws1.append([a, b])

newRa.save(filename='/Users/Ians/Desktop/newRwa.xlsx')
```

Comment: It works, thank you! It doesn't solve the puzzle what's wrong with saving cells to regular file though?

Comment: Great, could you please accept the answer if it solved your problem? 
The reason why it works is that xlsx files are binary; you can't just append unicode strings to them. The `openpyxl` library 'translates' your unicode data to something that the xlsx format can understand.